# How to launch a static html file in Visual Studio Code with a Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an older, static HTML website that I maintain. I like Visual Studio Code on my Mac, so I want to start doing my editing in there. I know how to configure Code to debug .NET Core apps; similarly I'd just like to launch a static HTML page (preferably the index page) in Visual Studio Code, as if I were debugging (like with a keyboard shortcut). The action would just be opening the page in a browser. How would I do that in Visual Studio Code's debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great non-StackOverflow answer at [Webucator.com](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/06/launch-files-browser-visual-studio-code/). I then just had to modify their solution slightly. The instructions were:

1. Open the Command Palette (shortcut is `cmd + shift + p` on a OXS)
2. Then type in `Configure Task Runner` and select it. When I selected Task Runner it opened the `task.json` file.
3. I then copied over the code there and replaced it with this code:

   `{
   "version": "0.1.0",
       "command": "Chrome",
       "osx": {
           "command": "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
       },
       "args": ["index.html"]
   }`

When I press `cmd + shift + b` (so long as nothing else is bound to that command on my machine), it opened the index page in the browser.

Alternatively, I could have set the args to `"args": ["${file}"]` and it would have attempted to open *any* file I happened to have open in Code inside of Chrome. However, I found this less desirable since it also tried to open up files that are not browsable in the project.